# Using distinct for specific column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Followinq query is possible in oracle

```
select DISTINCT(COLA), COLB 
from TABLEA
```

In this query,

1. Will this query returns distinct values for the combination of COLA and COLB?
2. If this query returns distinct value for the COLA alone, then what should be the COLB value for selected COLA?
3. Or if we have multiple records with same COLA value, will this query throws error?

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It is always applied to **all** columns of the select list. writing `distinct (cola), colb` is **exactly** the same as `distinct cola, colb` (the parentheses are totally useless). Details are in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55272

Comment: In that case, how to achieve distinct for particular rows alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the query returns distinct values for the combination of COLA and COLB.

Examine the syntax:
[image]

Note, that **DISTINCT/UNIQUE/ALL** can be only placed after SELECT and before of the first expression in the select list.
The documentation says that:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

> **DISTINCT | UNIQUE**
>
> Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one
>   copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are
>   synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each
>   expression in the select list.
>
> **ALL**
>
> Specify ALL if you want the database to return all rows selected,
>   including all copies of duplicates. The default is ALL.

The above means, that DISTINCT/UNIQUE is always applied to the whole select list, not to individual columns